# Message extension sign-in not working properly

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, imessage-extension

I have a message extension in the MS team, when I am trying to sign in it generates a pop-up with a validation code. I encountered this situation for the first time before that I just only need to enter the credentials.

```
const signInLink = await context.adapter.getSignInLink(context, this.connectionName);
    
return {
  composeExtension: {
  type: 'auth',
  suggestedActions: {
  actions: [{
    type: 'openUrl',
    value: signInLink,
    title: 'MedxPlanner Authentication'
  }]
 }}
};
```

[image]

can you guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hi @gaurav, we are working on it , we will update you soon.

Comment: Could you please share the sample or documentation link you are following?

Comment: Yeah, all good now and working. @ChetanSharma-msft

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, it is also not working in our case, and it stopped working sudden. Can you let us know what additional information need to send?

Answer (score 0):

To implement authentication for messaging extension, you need to use below code snippet:

```
{
  "composeExtension":{
    "type":"auth",
    "suggestedActions":{
      "actions":[
        {
          "type": "openUrl",
          "value": "{SignInLink}",
          "title": "{Sign in to this app}"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reference sample link:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config

Comment: The above code is similar to the one I have, meaning the code was never wrong and there are no implementation errors - there was some investigation done by MSFT as you can read from comments and it got fixed.